# Why is function not working sometimes in python?

Tags: python, function, file, variables, text-files

```
import time

def taym():
    time.sleep(5)

def getprice():
    myfile = open('C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\Python\\html1.html')
    txt = myfile.read()
    t = txt.find("$")
    it = float(txt[t-4:t])

it=8
while it != 1000:
    getprice()
    if it <= 4.74:
        print("Price is Ok!")
        taym()
    else: 
        print("The price of the coffee beans is "+txt[t-4:t+1])
        taym()
```

When I run this code in python3, I get an error message like this:

```
"print("The price of the coffee beans is "+txt[t-4:t+1])
NameError: name 'txt' is not defined."
```

I know I could use the original code from `getprice()` inside the loop, but I need to know why doesn't it work when I have a function that I call.

Comment: Your function `getprice()` seems to change an use variables: `txt, t, it`, but these are local to that function. Your main loop uses variables with those names, but they are not the same variables. Perhaps you meant to return them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I agree with @Gelineau, Your code should look like this:

```
import time
def taym():
    time.sleep(5)
def getprice():
    myfile=open('C:\\Users\\DELL\\Desktop\\Python\\html1.html')
    txt=myfile.read()
    t=txt.find("$")
    it=float(txt[t-4:t])
    return it, txt, t

it = 8
while it != 1000:
    it, txt, t = getprice()
    if it<=4.74:
        print("Price is Ok!")
        taym()
    else: 
        print("The price of the coffee beans is "+txt[t-4:t+1])
        taym()
```

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176228/discussion-between-juanpa-arrivillaga-and-quamrana).

Answer (score 6):

The variable txt is defined in `getprice` function, you cannot use it outside of this function.

You have got the same problem with `it` by the way

Answer (score 0):

The variable "txt" is out of scope from the place you called it. It's defined in the function but used in the while (out of scope).